# Filter multiple list values

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have one master list containing list of elements. I want to filter out some of the records from the list based on two filter conditions. I want to filter based on domain and orgs as shown below.without foreach loop can this comparsion be done on the mainLst ?

```
domains = "ABC/XYZ,RTG,YUT,WED"; //Comma seperated values
orgs = "FA,TR,WE,QW,ER"; // Comma seperated values
MainLst contains single domain and org for each record.

var mainLst = MasterData();
var filterDomain = lst.Where(c => c.domain == domains && c.orgs == orgs).ToList();
```

Comment: "based on two filter conditions" then you need to combine both filter conditions either by OR `||` or AND `&&` in the same `Where` call

Comment: actually your question is not really clear to me. "Comma seperated values" does that mean that you would like to match any of those values with `c.domain` ? or do you look for the string `"ABC/XYZ,RTG,YUT,WED"` as a whole ?

Comment: match any of those values with c.domain not as a whole

Comment: ok after you edit I am a little more confused. So if you do what I suggested already what is the outcome? and what did you expect ?

Comment: What's your expect result?

Comment: then split by `,` and use `Contains(c.domain)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
mainLst.Where(c => domains.Split(',').Contains(c.domain) && 
                   orgs.Split(',').Contains(c.org)).ToList();
```

This will split the domains and orgs by ', ' getting 2 lists that you can use in the filters.

The LINQ query then checks, for each item in mainLst, that the domain **and** the org is contained in those lists, applying both filters as you need.

Comment: You are right @MongZhu, sorry for the quick answer. I edited the answer. OP: if you have any questions regarding this solution please let me know.

Comment: #nitpick - `.ToList()` creates a copy, which may be unnecessary, depending on how the result is used.

Answer (score 0):

Split the list using `Split` method and use `LINQ` to fetch matching records.

```
        var domains = "ABC/XYZ,RTG,YUT,WED"; //Comma seperated values
        var orgs = "FA,TR,WE,QW,ER";

        var domainArray = domains.Split(',');
        var orgsArray = orgs.Split(',');

        var mainLst = new List<MasterData>();
        var filterDomain = from md in mainLst
                           join dm in domainArray on md.Domain equals dm
                           join or in orgsArray on md.Organization equals or
                           select md;
```